# "in that" vs. "because"

Tags: word-usage

As per [lexico](https://www.lexico.com/en/definition/in), "in that" means

> For the reason that (used to specify the respect in which a statement is true)

Consider this example from lexico

> ‘I was fortunate **in that** I had friends’

Does the following essentially mean the same thing?

> I was fortunate **because** I had friends

Comment: Yes, shiqangpan: *essentially* it does mean the same thing.

Comment: in that, because, for (as a conjunction), etc. are generally interchangeable.  Here, the second one is more idiomatic.